# Как правильно заполнить раскрывающийся список?

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных

Есть html форма с раскрывающимся списком, mysql база данных с таблицей с названиями отделов предприятия. Собственно нужно подставить названия отделов из БД в форму в тег option вместо значений 1, 2, 3.
Изначально было так:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputDepartment">Отдел</label>
          <select class="form-control">
                 <option style="display:none">Выберите отдел</option>
                 <option>1</option>
                 <option>2</option>
                 <option>3</option>
          </select>
</div>
```

Затем попробовал сделать так:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="inputDepartment">Отдел</label>
         <select class="form-control">
              <?php
                  $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT department FROM department");
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                   {
                      echo '<option value=" '.$row['id'].' "> '.$row['department'].' </option>';
                   }
               ?>
          </select>

</div>
```

В итоге список пустой, хотя подключение к базе я сделал. Да еще и стал игнорироваться весь html код после данного php кода. Использую bootstrap.
Подключение к базе сделал в файле connect.php, который подключил к index.php через `require_once('../../connect.php')`:

```
<?php
 $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
 $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'support') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных:');
?>
```

Comment: Правильно будет использовать шаблонизатор а-ля twig

Comment: @ArchDemon это кто сказал?

Comment: @РашенБеар, принцип единственной ответственности.

Comment: @ArchDemon прямо про twig в нем сказано? С таким же успехом можно посоветовать автору использовать Docker, когда уместнее рассказать про var_dump()

Comment: @РашенБеар, если вы не заметили в моём комментарии twig был приведён как пример. Использование шаблонизатора позволяет разделить ответственность. Если вы не согласны, то это ваше право

Answer (score 0):

Это должен быть файл с расширением .php что сервер понимал php код который будет выводить твои данные.

$options - тут твои данные которые ты получил из базы данных, или ты не знаешь как из получить из базы?

```html
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputDepartment">Отдел</label>
          <select class="form-control">
                 <option style="display:none">Выберите отдел</option>
                 <?php foreach($options as $item):?>
                  <option><?php echo $item?></option>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
               
          </select>
</div>
```